# Showing a search results page which has values from a multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [availableTrips] => Array
        (
            [AC] => false
            [arrivalTime] => 1830
            [availableSeats] => 4
            [boardingTimes] => Array
                (
                    [bpId] => 460319
                    [bpName] =>  Kalasipalyam 
                    [location] =>  Kalasipalyam 
                    [prime] => false
                    [time] => 1215
                )

            [busType] => Non A/C Semisleeper (2+2)
            [busTypeId] => 110
            [cancellationPolicy] => 0:8:100:0;8:24:50:0;24:-1:15:0
            [departureTime] => 1215
            [doj] => 2014-06-18T00:00:00+05:30
            [droppingTimes] => Array
                (
                    [bpId] => 559663
                    [bpName] =>  Mananthavaadi 
                    [location] =>  Mananthavaadi 
                    [prime] => false
                    [time] => 390
                )

            [fares] => 650
            [id] => 100102612640227182
            [idProofRequired] => false
            [nonAC] => true
            [operator] => 5127
            [partialCancellationAllowed] => false
            [routeId] => 100102600000227182
            [seater] => true
            [sleeper] => false
            [travels] => SKS Travels 
            [mTicketEnabled] => true
        )

)
```

which I get as a response from an API of bus ticket booking service.This is a search result of a single bus I got for a particular source and destination.For other source destination pairs,the result will be something can be like,if there is more than one bus on the route.

```
Array
(
    [availableTrips] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array         //1st bus in the search result
                (
                    [AC] => true
                    [arrivalTime] => 1845
                    [availableSeats] => 28
                    [boardingTimes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46768
                                    [bpName] => Kalasipalyam Main Road
                                    [location] => Kalasipalyam Main Road
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1260
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46774
                                    [bpName] => Christ University
                                    [location] => Christ University
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1280
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46771
                                    [bpName] => Madiwala
                                    [location] => Madiwala
                                    [prime] => true
                                    [time] => 1305
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46776
                                    [bpName] => Electronic City Toll Gate
                                    [location] => Electronic City Toll Gate
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1330
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46778
                                    [bpName] => Bommasandra Post Office
                                    [location] => Bommasandra Post Office
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1340
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46779
                                    [bpName] => Attibele
                                    [location] => Attibele
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1350
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46780
                                    [bpName] => Hosur
                                    [location] => Hosur
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1360
                                )

                        )

                    [busType] => Volvo Multiaxle A/C Seater Semi Sleeper (2+2)
                    [busTypeId] => 101
                    [cancellationPolicy] => 0:12:100:0;12:-1:10:0
                    [departureTime] => 1305
                    [doj] => 2014-06-18T00:00:00+05:30
                    [droppingTimes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46886
                                    [bpName] => Edapally Toll Gate
                                    [location] => Edapally Toll Gate
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1825
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46884
                                    [bpName] => Palarivattam
                                    [location] => Palarivattam
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1830
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46882
                                    [bpName] => Vytla junction
                                    [location] => Vytla junction
                                    [prime] => true
                                    [time] => 1845
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 46972
                                    [bpName] => MG Road
                                    [location] => MG Road
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1860
                                )

                        )

                    [fares] => 1000.00
                    [id] => 200855412640007772
                    [idProofRequired] => false
                    [nonAC] => false
                    [operator] => 7478
                    [partialCancellationAllowed] => true
                    [routeId] => 200855400000007772
                    [seater] => true
                    [sleeper] => false
                    [travels] => Shama Transport
                    [mTicketEnabled] => true
                )

            [1] => Array   //2nd bus in the search result
                (
                    [AC] => true
                    [arrivalTime] => 1710
                    [availableSeats] => 33
                    [boardingTimes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34106
                                    [bpName] => Kalasipalyam Main Road
                                    [location] => Kalasipalyam Main Road
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1080
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34099
                                    [bpName] => Dairy circle
                                    [location] => Dairy circle
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1095
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34098
                                    [bpName] => Christ University
                                    [location] => Christ University
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1100
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34093
                                    [bpName] => Madiwala
                                    [location] => Madiwala
                                    [prime] => true
                                    [time] => 1170
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34103
                                    [bpName] => Electronic City Toll Gate
                                    [location] => Electronic City Toll Gate
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1185
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34109
                                    [bpName] => Narayana Hridayalaya
                                    [location] => Narayana Hridayalaya
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1195
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34095
                                    [bpName] => Attibele
                                    [location] => Attibele
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1200
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34114
                                    [bpName] => Bommasandra Post Office
                                    [location] => Bommasandra Post Office
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1210
                                )

                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                    [bpId] => 34112
                                    [bpName] => Hosur
                                    [location] => Hosur
                                    [prime] => false
                                    [time] => 1215
                                )

                        )

                    [busType] => Volvo Multiaxle A/C Seater Semi Sleeper (2+2)
                    [busTypeId] => 101
                    [cancellationPolicy] => 0:12:100:0;12:-1:10:0
                    [departureTime] => 1170
                    [doj] => 2014-06-18T00:00:00+05:30
                    [droppingTimes] => Array
                        (
                            [bpId] => 45746
                            [bpName] => Vytala Bye Pass
                            [location] => Vyttila
                            [prime] => true
                            [time] => 1710
                        )

                    [fares] => 1100.00
                    [id] => 200855412640007290
                    [idProofRequired] => false
                    [nonAC] => false
                    [operator] => 6708
                    [partialCancellationAllowed] => true
                    [routeId] => 200855400000007290
                    [seater] => true
                    [sleeper] => false
                    [travels] => Atlas Travels
                    [mTicketEnabled] => true
                )
```

This goes on and on depending on the number of results.

This is the part of code which outputs the results above.

```
$availableBuses = json_decode($availableTrips,true);

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($availableBuses);
            echo "</pre>";
```

Now what I am trying to do is,to loop and parse through this array output the results into some div like.

```
<h1>Search results </h1>
<div>Bus name:<?php echo $ availableBuses['availableTrips']['travels'];?>Boarding place:<?php echo $availableBuses['availableTrips']['boradingTimes']['location']</div>
```

THe above will look like

```
**Search Results**
Bus name : SKS Travels
Boarding place : Kalasipalyam
```

if there are more results the above will be repeated as

```
         **Search Results**
        Bus name : SKS Travels
        Boarding place : Kalasipalyam

        Bus name : 1 Travels
        Boarding place : place 1

        Bus name : 2 Travels
        Boarding place : place 2 
.......
```

Im unable to parse this complex array properly

I have tried

```
 $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
         new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($availableTrips, TRUE)),
         RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
         foreach( $jsonIterator as $output)
                 {
            echo $output['travels'];
                    echo $output['droppingTimes']['location'];
              }
```

But I couldnt get what I wanted.I want to repeats the div with appropriate contents as the number of bus increase.

**I know this can be some dumb questions around,but Im finding it really hard to get through nor google did helped.If someone here could help me will be of great help

Thanks.

**Please excuse the long question,didnt find another way to explain this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the next array :

```
$availableBuses = Array
    (
    "availableTrips" => Array
        (
        "0" => Array         //1st bus in the search result
            (
            "AC" => "true",
            "arrivalTime" => "1845",
            "availableSeats" => "28",
            "boardingTimes" => Array
                (
                "0" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46768",
                    "bpName" => "Kalasipalyam Main Road",
                    "location" => "Kalasipalyam Main Road",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1260"
                ),
                "1" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46774",
                    "bpName" => "Christ University",
                    "location" => "Christ University",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1280"
                ),
                "2" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46771",
                    "bpName" => "Madiwala",
                    "location" => "Madiwala",
                    "prime" => "true",
                    "time" => "1305"
                ),
                "3" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46776",
                    "bpName" => "Electronic City Toll Gate",
                    "location" => "Electronic City Toll Gate",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1330"
                ),
                "4" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46778",
                    "bpName" => "Bommasandra Post Office",
                    "location" => "Bommasandra Post Office",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1340"
                ),
                "5" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46779",
                    "bpName" => "Attibele",
                    "location" => "Attibele",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1350"
                ),
                "6" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46780",
                    "bpName" => "Hosur",
                    "location" => "Hosur",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1360"
                ),
            ),
            "busType" => "Volvo Multiaxle A/C Seater Semi Sleeper (2+2)",
            "busTypeId" => "101",
            "cancellationPolicy" => "0:12:100:0;12:-1:10:0",
            "departureTime" => "1305",
            "doj" => "2014-06-18T00:00:00+05:30",
            "droppingTimes" => Array
                (
                "0" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46886",
                    "bpName" => "Edapally Toll Gate",
                    "location" => "Edapally Toll Gate",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1825",
                ),
                "1" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46884",
                    "bpName" => "Palarivattam",
                    "location" => "Palarivattam",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1830"
                ),
                "2" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46882",
                    "bpName" => "Vytla junction",
                    "location" => "Vytla junction",
                    "prime" => "true",
                    "time" => "1845"
                ),
                "3" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "46972",
                    "bpName" => "MG Road",
                    "location" => "MG Road",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1860"
                )
            ),
            "fares" => "1000.00",
            "id" => "200855412640007772",
            "idProofRequired" => "false",
            "nonAC" => "false",
            "operator" => "7478",
            "partialCancellationAllowed" => "true",
            "routeId" => "200855400000007772",
            "seater" => "true",
            "sleeper" => "false",
            "travels" => "Shama Transport",
            "mTicketEnabled" => "true"
        ),
        "1" => Array   //2nd bus in the search result
            (
            "AC" => "true",
            "arrivalTime" => "1710",
            "availableSeats" => "33",
            "boardingTimes" => Array
                (
                "0" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34106",
                    "bpName" => "Kalasipalyam Main Road",
                    "location" => "Kalasipalyam Main Road",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1080",
                ),
                "1" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34099",
                    "bpName" => "Dairy circle",
                    "location" => "Dairy circle",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1095"
                ),
                "2" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34098",
                    "bpName" => "Christ University",
                    "location" => "Christ University",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1100"
                ),
                "3" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34093",
                    "bpName" => "Madiwala",
                    "location" => "Madiwala",
                    "prime" => "true",
                    "time" => "1170"
                ),
                "4" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34103",
                    "bpName" => "Electronic City Toll Gate",
                    "location" => "Electronic City Toll Gate",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1185"
                ),
                "5" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34109",
                    "bpName" => "Narayana Hridayalaya",
                    "location" => "Narayana Hridayalaya",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1195"
                ),
                "6" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34095",
                    "bpName" => "Attibele",
                    "location" => "Attibele",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1200"
                ),
                "7" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34114",
                    "bpName" => "Bommasandra Post Office",
                    "location" => "Bommasandra Post Office",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1210"
                ),
                "8" => Array
                    (
                    "bpId" => "34112",
                    "bpName" => "Hosur",
                    "location" => "Hosur",
                    "prime" => "false",
                    "time" => "1215"
                )
            ),
            "busType" => "Volvo Multiaxle A/C Seater Semi Sleeper (2+2)",
            "busTypeId" => "101",
            "cancellationPolicy" => "0:12:100:0;12:-1:10:0",
            "departureTime" => "1170",
            "doj" => "2014-06-18T00:00:00+05:30",
            "droppingTimes" => Array
                (
                "bpId" => "45746",
                "bpName" => "Vytala Bye Pass",
                "location" => "Vyttila",
                "prime" => "true",
                "time" => "1710"
            ),
            "fares" => "1100.00",
            "id" => "200855412640007290",
            "idProofRequired" => "false",
            "nonAC" => "false",
            "operator" => "6708",
            "partialCancellationAllowed" => "true",
            "routeId" => "200855400000007290",
            "seater" => "true",
            "sleeper" => "false",
            "travels" => "Atlas Travels",
            "mTicketEnabled" => "true"
        )
    )
);
```

You could get what you want by doing :

```
$workingArrayForBuses = array();

if(isset($availableBuses['availableTrips']['AC'])){
    //ONE RESULT
    $workingArrayForBuses[] = $availableBuses['availableTrips'];
}else{
    //MULTIPLE RESULTS
    $workingArrayForBuses = $availableBuses['availableTrips'];
}

echo '<h1>Search results</h1>';
foreach($workingArrayForBuses as $availableBuses){
    echo '<div>';
    echo 'Bus name : '.$availableBuses['travels'].'<br/>';
    $workingArrayForBoardings = array();
    if(isset($availableBuses['boardingTimes']['bpId'])){
        //ONE RESULT
        $workingArrayForBoardings[] = $availableBuses['boardingTimes'];
    }else{
        //MULTIPLE RESULTS
        $workingArrayForBoardings = $availableBuses['boardingTimes'];
    }
    echo 'Boarding place(s) :<br/>';
    foreach($workingArrayForBoardings as $boardingTimes){
        echo '- '.$boardingTimes['location'].'<br/>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

That would output :

```
Bus name : Shama Transport
Boarding place(s) :
- Kalasipalyam Main Road
- Christ University
- Madiwala
- Electronic City Toll Gate
- Bommasandra Post Office
- Attibele
- Hosur
Bus name : Atlas Travels
Boarding place(s) :
- Kalasipalyam Main Road
- Dairy circle
- Christ University
- Madiwala
- Electronic City Toll Gate
- Narayana Hridayalaya
- Attibele
- Bommasandra Post Office
- Hosur
```

Well, i guess you will need to update this to get exactly what you want.

Note : A problem there is, is the way i handle the single result and multiple results return array, the problem being the return array with only one result :

```
Array ( 
    'AC' => true
    ...
)
```

Instead of being

```
Array ( 
    [0] => array(
        'AC' => true
        ...
    )
)
```

Not satisfied with the trick i used to handle this, but i don't know how to do this another(better) way. If anyone got any idea, would be good to know !

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the response.Ill try this.This will be really helpful for a start.